# Alpha animator to a group element in AnimatedVectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Is it possible to apply an alpha animator to a `<group>` element instead of whole `<vector>` element in an AnimatedVectorDrawable? If not, is there any alternative to this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the `<group>` element doesn't have an alpha property.

As per the [VectorDrawable documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html), the parts of the VectorDrawable with alpha are the whole `<vector>` which has `android:alpha` and the `<path>` which has `android:strokeAlpha` and `android:fillAlpha`.

So if you want to animate the alpha of only part of the VectorDrawable you should animate the fillAlpha and/or strokeAlpha of the relevant paths.